# C++ string. why is the answer showing that string "dog" is greater than "cat", then "cat" is greater than "dog"?

Tags: c++

I'm not quite sure why the answer for the larger string ("cat" and "dog") is not consistent. I was doing some things with Linked Lists and the use of templates. My curiosity got me to revise templates and function overloading. If anyone can explain what is going on, I would appreciate it. 
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   // for the sake of simplicity. (otherwise, std::)

// Function overloading and the use of templates

// overloading the function larger
int larger(int, int);
char larger(char, char);
double larger(double, double);
string larger(string, string);

template <class elementType>
elementType anyLarger(elementType parameter1, elementType parameter2);


int main() {

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Function Overloading" << endl;

    cout << "larger(15, 27)            =  " << larger(15, 27) << endl;
    cout << "larger('X', 'P')          =  " << larger('X', 'P') << endl;
    cout << "larger(4.9, 3.2)          =  " << larger(4.9, 3.2) << endl;
    cout << "larger(cat, dog)          =  " << larger("cat", "dog") << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Using the function template to find the larger of two items" << endl;
    cout << "anyLarger(15, 27)         =  " << anyLarger(15, 27) << endl;
    cout << "anyLarger('X', 'P')       =  " << anyLarger('X', 'P') << endl;
    cout << "anyLarger(4.9, 3.2)       =  " << anyLarger(4.9, 3.2) << endl;
    cout << "anyLarger(cat, dog)       =  " << anyLarger("cat", "dog") << endl;
    cout << endl;


    cout << "Compare two strings:   cat, dog" << endl;
    if ("cat" >= "dog") {
      cout << "cat is greater than dog" << endl;
    }
    else {
      cout << "dog is greater than cat" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    string strCat = "cat";
    string strDog = "dog";
    cout << "string strCat = cat" << endl;
    cout << "string strDog = dog" << endl;
    if (strCat >= strDog) {
      cout << "strCat is greater than strDog" << endl;
    }
    else {
      cout << "strDog is greater than strCat" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
} // end main 

// Overloading larger
int larger(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= y)
      return x;
    else 
      return y;
}

char larger(char a, char b) {
    if (a >= b)
      return a;
    else 
      return b;
}

double larger(double p, double q) {
    if (p >= q)
      return p;
    else
      return q;
}

string larger(string y, string z) {
    if (y >= z)
      return y;
    else
      return z;
}


// Defining the template function
template <class elementType>
elementType anyLarger(elementType parameter1, elementType parameter2)
{
    if (parameter1 >= parameter2)
      return parameter1; 
    else
      return parameter2;
}
```

Here is the result after running the program.

```
Function Overloading
larger(15, 27)            =  27
larger('X', 'P')          =  X
larger(4.9, 3.2)          =  4.9
larger(cat, dog)          =  dog

Using the function template to find the larger of two items
anyLarger(15, 27)         =  27
anyLarger('X', 'P')       =  X
anyLarger(4.9, 3.2)       =  4.9
anyLarger(cat, dog)       =  cat

Compare two strings:   cat, dog
cat is greater than dog

string strCat = cat
string strDog = dog
strDog is greater than strCat
```

==============================================

## Update: Made some changes and used strcmp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

// Function overloading and the use of templates


// overloading the function larger
int larger(int, int);
char larger(char, char);
double larger(double, double);
string larger(string, string);


template <class elementType>
elementType anyLarger(elementType parameter1, elementType parameter2);


int main(){

  cout << endl;
  cout << "// Function Overloading" << endl;


  cout << "larger(15, 27)              =  " << larger(15, 27) << endl;
  cout << "larger('X', 'P')            =  " << larger('X', 'P') << endl;
  cout << "larger(4.9, 3.2)            =  " << larger(4.9, 3.2) << endl;
  cout << "larger(\"cat\", \"dog\")        =  " << larger("cat", "dog") << endl;

  cout << endl;
  cout << "// Using the function template to find the larger of two items" << endl;
  cout << "anyLarger(15, 27)           =  " << anyLarger(15, 27) << endl;
  cout << "anyLarger('X', 'P')         =  " << anyLarger('X', 'P') << endl;
  cout << "anyLarger(4.9, 3.2)         =  " << anyLarger(4.9, 3.2) << endl;
  cout << "anyLarger(\"cat\", \"dog\")     =  " << anyLarger("cat", "dog") << endl;
  cout << endl;


  cout << "// Compare two strings using >= :   \"cat\", \"dog\"" << endl;
  if ("cat" >= "dog") {
    cout << "\"cat\" is greater than \"dog\"" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "\"dog\" is greater than \"cat\"" << endl;
  }

  cout << endl;
  cout << "// The use of variables: strCat and strDog. Compare using >=" << endl;
  string strCat = "cat";
  string strDog = "dog";
  cout << "string strCat = \"cat\";" << endl;
  cout << "string strDog = \"dog\";" << endl;
  if (strCat >= strDog) {
    cout << "strCat is greater than strDog" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "strDog is greater than strCat" << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;


  cout << "// Using strcmp.   strcmp(\"cat\", \"dog\")" << endl; 
  int result = strcmp("cat", "dog");
  if (result > 0) {
    cout << "\"cat\" is greater than \"dog\"" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "\"dog\" is greater than \"cat\"" << endl;
  }
}

// Overloading larger
int larger(int x, int y) {
if (x >= y)
    return x;
  else 
    return y;
}


char larger(char a, char b) {
  if (a >= b)
    return a;
  else 
    return b;
}


double larger(double p, double q) {
  if (p >= q)
    return p;
  else
    return q;
}

string larger(string y, string z) {
  if (y >= z)
    return y;
  else
    return z;
}


// Defining the template function
template <class elementType>
elementType anyLarger(elementType parameter1, elementType parameter2)
{
  if (parameter1 >= parameter2)
    return parameter1; 
  else
    return parameter2;
}
```

================

## Update: Output

```
// Function Overloading
larger(15, 27)              =  27
larger('X', 'P')            =  X
larger(4.9, 3.2)            =  4.9
larger("cat", "dog")        =  dog

// Using the function template to find the larger of two items
anyLarger(15, 27)           =  27
anyLarger('X', 'P')         =  X
anyLarger(4.9, 3.2)         =  4.9
anyLarger("cat", "dog")     =  cat

// Compare two strings using >= :   "cat", "dog"
"cat" is greater than "dog"

// The use of variables: strCat and strDog. Compare using >=
string strCat = "cat";
string strDog = "dog";
strDog is greater than strCat

// Using strcmp.   strcmp("cat", "dog")
"dog" is greater than "cat"
```

Comment: I believe anyLarger and "" string comparison compares `char*`, while larger and string variables compares `std::string`'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal string `"cat"` and `"dog"` are actually *pointers* to arrays of characters when you come to compare them, so the greatest will be the one that happens to be stored in memory at a higher location.

Your `string larger(string y, string z)` works because `std::string` can be constructed from a `char*` and so `"cat"` and `"dog"` get converted to `std::string` objects before being compared.

The *template* function, on the other hand, accepts them as their actual types which, when passed as parameters, become `const char*` and only their addresses get compared.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Based on your explanation and a look at the ASCII table (Dec for d = 100, and Dec for c = 99), it would be correct to say that the template function gives an "incorrect" answer, right?

Comment: @User_fts The template function simply doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't compare the strings. It compares their position in memory. Every variable is stored in memory at a specific location and that location is referred to by a number. Your template function compares those numbers.

Comment: Galik, thank you. That makes sense. if you would use a single template function that would work for int, double, char and string, how would you implement it?
(the template function Prazuber wrote would work when you need to compare using strcmp)

Comment: @User_fts If you want it to accept string literals like `"cat"` then you can't do it just with a template function. @prazuber's answer has a solution.

Comment: Galik.
Sounds good. You're very knowledgeable with the C++ language, what has been the most useful resource or way of learning for you? If you can't discuss that on here, based on the type of questions permitted, would you mind if I reach you in another means?

Comment: @User_fts I would recommend working methodically through a good book, bring any problems to this forum. Don't just get any book because there are so many bad books. I suggest choosing from this list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list Also, if you have [IRC](https://webchat.freenode.net/) you can chat/lurk in Freenode's `##c++`, `##c++-basic` & `##c++-general`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Galik. I appreciate your suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 10):

You are not lexicographically comparing strings in both cases.

```
"cat" >= "dog"
```

This is comparing `char` pointers because the type of the literals `"cat"` and `"dog"` is `const char*`. It could give either result, depending on how the compiler decided to materialize the literals.

To lexicographically compare C-style strings (including literals like these) the function `strcmp` must be used instead.

```
strCat >= strDog
```

This is comparing strings lexicographically because `std::string` provides comparison operators that explicitly implement this kind of comparison.

Comment: Heck, it could give [both results](https://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/) since it's undefined behaviour to compare (excluding (in)equality) two "unrelated" pointers.

Comment: @chris: Hehe, so true.

Comment: Technically, the type of the literals `"cat"` and `"dog"` is `const char[4]`, and can be implicitly converted to `const char*`.

Comment: @chris: correct. `std::greater`, on the other hand, does provide a total order (but it's still unpredictable).

Comment: Jon, thank you very much. I recently saw something about lexicographically comparing strings. Do you know/have any references/tutorials that you might be able to point me to?

Answer (score 4):

```
"cat" >= "dog"
```

You are comparing pointers but not the actual values. Use `strcmp`.

Comment: Thank you, Mahesh. I used strcmp. I got "dog" as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

That's because string literal (e.g. `"cat"`) isn't of type `std::string`. You're doing a pointer comparison on two unrelated arrays of `const char`.

Comment: Thank you, milleniumbug. I appreciate your point on pointer comparison.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned, in your line

```
cout << "anyLarger(cat, dog)       =  " << anyLarger("cat", "dog") << endl;
```

you are invoking `anyLarger<const char &[]>`, i.e. you call `anyLarger` with string literal arguments, which indeed boils down to comparing pointers instead of strings. You can fix this by either calling your function with std::string arguments by one of the following lines:

```
larger("cat", "dog");
anyLarger<std::string>("cat", "dog");
anyLarger(std::string("cat"), std::string("dog"));
anyLarger("cat"s, "dog"s); // C++14
```

or you could do a template specialization for string literals (or just any C-type strings, whatever you choose):

```
template <>
elementType anyLarger<char*>(char* parameter1, char* parameter2)
{
    if (strcmp(parameter1, parameter2) >= 0)
      return parameter1; 
    else
      return parameter2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Prazuber. I like your implementation for the template function. In my update, the use of strcmp produced "dog" as being greater. Running your version should produce "dog"
I would give it another shot.